# How to speed up WSL2 internet download speed

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, hyper-v, bandwidth, wsl-2, hypervisor

I tried to use Windows Subsystem For Linux(WSL) 2 to use ubuntu 20.04 on Windows 10 and 11. But it has too bad internet speed in WSL2 ubuntu system. I had tried ubuntu on WSL1 as well, it also has too bad speed. It has almost 1/10 internet speed than host PC's internet speed in Task Manager / Performance.

I noticed that WSL Ethernet is working through Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter.

**Is there any way to increase internet download speed in WSL2 by adjusting Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter Band-Width Limit or doing something else?**

Comment: A good question, just off-topic here IMHO since it isn't directly programming-related.  Would highly suggest reposting this over on [Super User](https://superuser.com).  Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that the network is slow? If you download into a local virtual disk, which is a shared directory with your host system, you will experience exactly the same symptomes. Btw, WSL2 is no more than a virtualization engine, and not a really competent one. My experiences about VirtualBox are much better.